# For polynomial with degree 3, when $a + ib$ is a root show $a-ib$ is a root, and it also has a rational root.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

> Let $p(x)$ be a cubic (i.e. degree $3$) polynomial with
>   rational coefficients. Suppose $p(x)$ has a root of the
>   form $a + ib$, where $a, b$ are rational,
>
> Prove that $a-ib$ is also a root of $p(x)$, and that $p(x)$ must also have a rational root.

My Attempts:

By assumption, we have:
\begin{align}
p(a + ib)
&=c_3(a + ib)^3+c_2(a + ib)^2+c_1(a + ib)+c_0\\
&=a^3 c_3 
+ 3 i a^2 b c_3 
+ a^2 c_2 
+ 2 i a b c_2 
+ a c_1
+ i b c_1 
- 3 a b^2 c_3 
- i b^3 c_3 
- b^2 c_2 
+ c_0\\
&=0
\end{align}
This implies:
$$
c_0=
- a^3 c_3 
- 3 i a^2 b c_3 
- a^2 c_2 
- 2 i a b c_2 
- a c_1
- i b c_1 
+ 3 a b^2 c_3 
+ i b^3 c_3 
+ b^2 c_2$$
Then for $p(a - ib)$ we have:
\begin{align}
p(a - ib)
&=c_3(a - ib)^3+c_2(a - ib)^2+c_1(a - ib)+c_0\\
&=
a^3 c_3 
+ a^2 c_2 
+ a c_1 
+ i b^3 c_3
- 3 i a^2 b c_3  
- 3 a b^2 c_3 
- b^2 c_2 - i b c_1
- 2 i a b c_2 \\
&- a^3 c_3 
- a^2 c_2 
- a c_1
+ i b^3 c_3
- 3 i a^2 b c_3
+ 3 a b^2 c_3 
+ b^2 c_2
- i b c_1  
- 2 i a b c_2 
\\
&=- 6 i a^2 b c_3+ 2i b^3 c_3- 2i b c_1- 4 i a b c_2 \\
\end{align}

I think this isn't a good approache, and I'm stucked now,
 that didn't give $p(a - ib)=0$ $\dots$ how do I prove this $?$

Any help or hint or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: If $P(z)=0$ then $\overline{P(z)}$ is also 0 and here your polynomial has rational coefficients.

Comment: Your first implication should instead be
$$
c_0 + a c_1 + a^2 c_2 - b^2 c_2 + a^3 c_3 - 3 a b^2 c_3=0
$$
and
$$
b (c_1 + 2 a c_2 + 3 a^2 c_3 - b^2 c_3)=0
$$
for the real and imaginary parts respectively. (Rather than as a whole) Expanding for $p(a-ib)$ should give you the same real part and a negative imaginary part, so it's still zero. (You can check via your expansion directly.)

Comment: This will hold if $a,b,c$ are real and rational. Or more generally, if $a/b, b/c, c/a$ are real and rational.

Comment: The tag "elementary-number-theory" is inappropriate. The tag should be "polynomials".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem really ought to assume that $b\neq0$. I will assume so in the below answer.

For a polynomial with real coefficients (including if the coefficients are rational), we have $p(\bar z)=\overline{p(z)}$. If $p(a+bi)$ (and therefore $\overline{p(a+bi)}$) happens to be $0$, then $p(\overline{a+bi})=p(a-bi)$ must be zero also.

And since both $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ are roots of $p$, that means that
$$
(x-a-bi)(x-a+bi)=x^2 -2ax+a^2+b^2
$$
is a factor of $p(x)$ (this is where $b \neq 0$ comes in; if $b = 0$, then the two roots from the preceeding paragraph are really the *same* root, and thus we don't know that we can divide out by that one root twice). All coefficients here are rational, and performing the long division $p(x)\div (x^2 -2ax+a^2+b^2)$ can only ever keep all coefficients rational. The result of that division is therefore a degree 1 polynomial with rational coefficients, which thus must have a rational root.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Such a polynomial can be expressed as $$p(x){=k(x-a-ib)(x-a+ib)(x-c)\\=k(x^2+a^2+b^2-2xa)(x-c)}$$where $a,b,c\in\Bbb Q$ and $k\in\Bbb C$. Now, what can you say about $K$ and $c$ after expanding the terms?

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: let P be a polynomial from R[X].and degP>2.then if p(s)=0,one has p(s•)=0 where  s• is the conjugate of a.
Proof:
Using the fact that (a•+b•)=(a+b)• we are done

Answer (score 1):

Since a cubic always has a *real* root $r$, dividing the cubic by $x-r$ simplifies the problem to a quadratic. Just have to show if $a+ib$ is a root then $a-ib$ is also a root:
$$x^2-(a+ib+c+id)x+(a+ib)(c+id)=0$$
For the coefficients to be rational, we get conditions:
$$b+d=0\\bc+ad=0$$

Answer (score 1):

**$a-ib$ is also a root of $p$ :**

The conjugation $\sigma : z \mapsto \bar{z}$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $p$ has a root in $\mathbb{Q}[i]$, namely $z=a + ib$, we must have $$p(\bar{z}) = p(\sigma(z)) = \sigma(p(z)) = \sigma(0) = 0$$
Hence, $\bar{z} = a - ib$ is also a root of $p$.

**$p$ has a root in $\mathbb{Q}$ :**

Since $z$ and $\bar{z}$ are roots of $p$, we get that the polynomial $(X - z)(X - \bar{z})$ divides $p$. But $(X - z)(X - \bar{z}) = X^2 - 2aX +a^2-b^2 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$. Hence, the quotient $q:=\frac{p}{(X - z)(X - \bar{z})}$ is a degree 1 polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. Clearly, $q$ has a root, say $r$, in $\mathbb{Q}$. $r$ is the rational root of $p$.